# Swift: Perform Segue is throwing a found nil when unwrapping an Optional

Tags: swift, crash, segue, option-type

I know there's a couple of other post on a similar errors but looking at those they are happening in the prepare for segue method as the user attempts to pass some data. In my case, I am just trying to segue from one vc to another. The IBOutlet is linked up from Storyboard. I check the destination vc in prepare for segue and it exists. The crash happens after that method is called.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnShowAccount: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ivLaunch: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var vButtonWrapper: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnMissionLog: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnAccount: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNotes: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnInfo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnPrivacy: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnHelp: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //align button text to left
    btnAccount.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    btnMissionLog.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    btnNotes.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.ivLaunch.fadeOut(0.15)
    self.vButtonWrapper.fadeIn()
}

@IBAction func showAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAccountFromRoot", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print(segue.destination)
}
```

The error message doesn't point to which object the compiler is trying to unwrap:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

XCode is less than helpful as it displays the error in viewDidLoad, on first line of code, which obviously has already happened. (And if I comment out all viewDidLoad code it shows the error in viewDidAppear).

I do see this in the debug navigator:

```
; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A>((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I'm kind of stuck on this one.

Comment: Perhaps the class for the destinationVC is not set correctly in the Storyboard.  If it is using `ViewController` then the outlets would be `nil`.

Comment: The destination class has nothing in it. Just an empty VC. I meant the outlets in the originating view controller were hooked up.

Comment: @PruitIgoe then create a class of `UIViewController` call it `DesitinationVc`  and add it to the inspector attribute of the viewcontroller's class.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack crawl highly suggests that your destinationVC has type `ViewController` which is the same class that your first VC uses.

You can verify this by adding:

```
print(type(of: segue.destination))
```

to your `prepare(for:sender:)` method.  If it prints `ViewController`, then that is your problem.

In that case, the crash in `viewDidLoad` is when the destinationVC loads. Because it is set to `ViewController` instead of `UIViewController` (which is what you'd expect for a blank VC), the outlets are not connected so you get the unwrapping nil message when trying to access `btnAccount`. Fix the class for the blank view controller by deleting the **Class** in the *Identity Inspector*.

Once you've verified that that works.  Create a new class (that is a subclass of `UIViewController`) for your destinationVC and assign that class in the *Identify Inspector*.

Comment: That was first thing I check (see my code) and it printed the correct view controller. (lines 8/9 show it loading and appearing. But I do see what you are saying, right after it looks like it is trying to load the root viewcontroller again.

Comment: This resolved on it's own, not sure if I banged something on the keyboard that fixed it but now it's working.